# make four buttons width to fit for all screen size in swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

[image][image]
I am doing a sample project with size class and autolayout in swift.I have four buttons on top of the screen.How to set same width for all buttons with one pixel gap between them and make them fit for all screen size.
thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to make the button widths variable, but the same for all buttons. This can be accomplished like this:

1. Place the four buttons
2. Set the left margin constraint from the leftmost button
3. Set the right margin constraint from the rightmost button
4. Set horziontal distance constraints between the buttons to 1
5. Set the width constraints for all buttons to >= 10 (or any other
   value, this makes the width variable)
6. Set equal width constraints on all buttons (ctrl-drag from one button to the next and choose *equal width*. Repeat that for all buttons)

Comment: another option is to use a UIToolBar, and add buttons and spingy spaces to that.  It doesn't guarantee same sized buttons, but will be consistent with other UI

Comment: Please edit your question and include a screenshot with your current constraint settings.

Comment: You have set the button width to a fixed value (150). It should be a variable value. Try to set it to >= 10. The ">=" is important. Follow the steps I wrote in my answer

Comment: how to set variable value?

Comment: Edit the constraint, set it to **>=** 10, NOT **=** 10

Comment: updated question with output.why i am not getting it correctly?

Comment: looks like the left constraint is missing

Comment: should i set left constraints for all buttons?

Comment: Please delete all your constraints and follow exactly the steps in my answer. There should be a left constraint on the first button only. A right constraint on the last button only. Horizontal space constraints between the buttons. Width constraints (>= 10) on all buttons. And finally all buttons to equal widths.